# Regex match only numbers in a string

Tags: regex

Example i need take only numbers in bellow strings.

```
lori ipsum 1, 2 e 3 dorm kietjiojwoijdej 162, 131 e 107 m²

lori fsdfsd ipsum 2 e 3 dormitórios fsrfsrfrfrfkietjiojwoijdej 162, 131 e 107 m²

lori ipsum dfs 3 dorm kidfsrfrfrffretjiojwoijdej 62, 13 e 10 m²

lori ipsum 1 dormitórios kietjiojwoijdej 16, 31 e 107 m²
```

Desired output is:

```
[0] => 1, [1] => 2, [2] => 3

[0] => 2, [1] => 3

[0] => 3

[0] => 1
```

I try the follow regex:

```
(\d(?= dorms))|(\d(?= dormitórios))
```

My problem is with comma, spaces and "e" character, i dont what that in the result...

My test : [regextest](https://regex101.com/r/EC3Gyn/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your current regex [`(\d(?= dorms))|(\d(?= dormitórios))`](https://regex101.com/r/5XtlIu/1) you match only the 3 in `3 dormitórios` and the 1 in `1 dormitórios` because in your lookahead you specify a single whitespace followed by either `dorms` or `|`  `dormitórios`.

You don't match the 3 in `3 dorm` because you use `(?= dorms)` with an extra `s`.

Instead you could use 1 positive [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) instead of 2 with an optional non capturing group `(?:itórios)?` to match both variants and add a word boundary `\b` before and after the word you want to match.

[`\d(?=.*?\bdorm(?:itórios)?\b)`](https://regex101.com/r/Lp0ARq/1)

**Details**

- `\d` Match a single digit
- `(?=` Non capturing group

  - `.*?` Match any character zero or more times non greedy
  - `\b` Word boundary
  - `dorm(?:itórios)?` Match `dorm` or `dormitórios`
  - `\b` Word boundary
- `)` Close non capturing group